# How to set conditional colors based on the numbers on rows in gt?

Tags: r, gt

I am new to the `gt` package. I have a set of data like `t(mtcars))`. For example

```
     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout Valiant Duster 360 Merc 240D Merc 230 Merc 280
mpg      21.00        21.000      22.80         21.400             18.70   18.10      14.30     24.40    22.80    19.20
cyl       6.00         6.000       4.00          6.000              8.00    6.00       8.00      4.00     4.00     6.00
disp    160.00       160.000     108.00        258.000            360.00  225.00     360.00    146.70   140.80   167.60
hp      110.00       110.000      93.00        110.000            175.00  105.00     245.00     62.00    95.00   123.00
drat      3.90         3.900       3.85          3.080              3.15    2.76       3.21      3.69     3.92     3.92
wt        2.62         2.875       2.32          3.215              3.44    3.46       3.57      3.19     3.15     3.44
```

How to set colors based on the numbers on each row? I only know how to do it when it is the other way around. For example

```
data_color(columns = vars("mpg"), 
         colors = scales::col_numeric(c("red","green"),
                                      domain = c(0,30)))
```

Or any way to transpose at the end if I make the table with data in the form of `mtcars`? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like? It's kind of hard to know without seeing an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, but I might be off.

The disadvantage for this solution is that you need to change the indices depending on your dataset for the `rows` argument, and you'll need to know the row index of the variable that you want to add color to in the table.

```
head(as_tibble(t(mtcars))) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = where(is.numeric),
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("red", "green"),
      domain = c(0,30)
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    location = cells_body(
      columns = where(is.numeric),
      rows = 2:6
    ),
    style = list(cell_text(color = "black"),
                 cell_fill(color = "white"))
  )
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. What if I wanted to set a different color scheme for the 2nd row?

Comment: I don't think you could use this solution for a different color scheme for the 2nd row. The solution above is setting a color scheme for the entire table using `data_color`, and then removing the color from rows 2 through 6 with `tab_style`. There doesn't seem to be a `rows` argument for `data_color`

Comment: I see. Yes, a `rows` argument for `data_color` is exactly what I have been looking for. That would make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example: (R >= 4.1 for new pipe)

```
library(gt)
df <- t(mtcars) |> as.data.frame() |> subset(select = 1:5)
gt_tbl <- df |> gt() |> 
  tab_style(
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = `Datsun 710`,
      rows = `Datsun 710` > 30
    ),
    style = list(cell_text(color = 'red'))
  )
gt_tbl
```

Gives:
[image]